# impulse input and discontinuity in initial condition after

Tags: control-engineering, control-theory, mathematics

Consider a dynamical system as bellow that is subjected to an impulse input:

$\sum_{n=0}^N {a_n x^{(n)}}= f_0 \delta(t-t_0)$

the initial values are non-resting (all non-zero):

$x(t_0^-)=x_0\hspace{0.2cm} ;\hspace{0.2cm} x'(t_0^-)=x_1\hspace{0.2cm} ;\hspace{0.2cm} ... \hspace{0.2cm} ;\hspace{0.2cm} x^{(n-1)}(t_0^-)=x_{(n-1)} $.

How can I write the correct initial values for $t=t_0^+$? This is ambiguous since integrating the differential equation above, yields:

$ \sum_{n=1}^N a_n  \big[x^{(n-1)} (t_0^+)-x^{(n-1)} (t_0^-)\big] = \sum_{n=1}^N a_n  c_{n-1} = f_0$

where $c_i$s are the jumps in initial conditions. In literature, it is said that only the highest order will undergo a discontinuity, yet it's not clear for me why.

Comment: Welcome to Engineering Stack Exchange.  This seems like an assumption mde by the book.  If you assume a discontinuity in the highest term, then differentiate, all the differentials will have impulses - i.e. no visible discontinuity.  Therefore, this is an easy system to analyze as a first order.  Other solutions exist, but this is the easiest to model.

Comment: How can a finite order continuous model describe a delay?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked the question [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/411213/non-resting-initial-value-problem-with-impulsive-input) and I found the answer myself. This is really a simple one really. Here is my answer for this question:

> [...] I revisited this problem with another point of view which gives the answer right away. Since the $x$ is at least $N-1$ times differentiable, it's derivatives (up to order $N-2$) and itself must be continuous. So no shift until the last derivative. Using the my question's notation,
>
> $c_n =0\hspace{1cm} \forall n<N-1$
>
> $c_{N-1} =f_0/a_N$